# VSTO Ribbon Button Right-Click Event

Tags: c#, vsto, right-click, ribbon-control

I have a VSTO add-in that uses a custom ribbon, but it appears the only event on the ribbon buttons is a Click Event.  I was hoping there would be some way I could capture a right-click, which I would normally do using the `MouseDown` event, but no such option exists.

I also checked the `RibbonControlEventArgs,` and it does not have anything to indicate whether the click was a left or a right.

Is there an alternate control I can use or another way to handle a right-click, or are there any light-weight third party controls that would help?

I noticed that in Excel, for example, the native controls don't appear to handle a right-click, so I may be out of luck.  Right-clicking the ribbon appears to invoke an action on the ribbon itself, not on the control that has focus.

For what it's worth, my goal is this:  The ribbon has recently become crowded, so I have moved many buttons into a ribbon menu.  This works nicely.  What I'd like to do now is give the user an option to "elevate" selected buttons from the menu to the ribbon group -- for frequently used items.

[image: Ribbon Snapshot]

Comment: I'd love to do this as well. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regret to tell you but the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that. You can read more about the UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Good information...  thanks.  It seems the ribbon natively handles *some* of what I was seeking anyway, so maybe I was trying to be too cute.